# error running job using xavier initialization on google cloud machine learning

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm using the xavier conv2d method for initializing my variables like this:

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d()
variable = tf.get_variable(name=name,shape=shape,initializer=initializer)
```

the training runs locally using `gcloud ml-engine local train`, however it crashes when sending it as a job to the cloud.

The crash log: `"Module raised an exception <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>:-15."`

If I replace the xavier initializer by a random uniform initializer, the training works both on my local machine and on the cloud:

```
 initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.25,0.25)
```

I'm running gpu_enabled tensorflow version 1.01 on my local machine using python 2.7.13

Comment: Are you willing / able to share more of the log preceding the exit? There should be more details about the exception, although you may have to scroll up a bit and expand the entries.

Comment: @rhaertel80 here it is:
`The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 245. Program exit details: exit_code: 245 reason: "Error" message: "{\"exit_code\": -11}\n" started_at { seconds: 1490825252 } finished_at { seconds: 1490825349 } container_id: `
after that I get the signal 15 message. Does this help?

Comment: That's a SEGFAULT. Let me check if this is a known problem.